# Female symbol on PCB silkscreen?

Tags: pcb, symbol, certification, silkscreen

[image]

You can see the symbol on the upper right hand side of the board, what appears to be a pictogram of a woman wearing a dress, similar to a bathroom sign (?)

Wondering what this is.

Comment: If that's a camera sensor, maybe it's a reference for image orientation?

Comment: What is this thing you found it on?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think you're 100% right

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it is indeed a camera sensor, i think chris may be onto something

Comment: like chris said, this is to point out the orientation. But normally they do not point this out explicitly. Most of the times they think you can find it out, by the other things on the silkscreen like the V2.2 and the HD. As you can see on Raspberry pi camera modules, you can see the orientation due to the raspberry on it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is an orientation marking for this image sensor module. Since the module you are holding is square, allowing multiple assembly orientations during box-build, the correct orientation of the image sensor module can be inferred using the logo. Other pictograms used often are rectangles indicating the aspect ratio, X/Y coordinate vectors, the literals "F" or "4".